# Use .gitignore from parent directory to exclude files from search result

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm using a workspace with 2 different folders that are part of the same reposiory.
The .gitignore file for the directories is sitting in the above directory and not inside the folders.

The folder structure:

```
ParentDir
     .gitIgnore
     folder 1
     folder 2
```

Because of that VS Code doesn't exclude the files affected from .gitignore

Your help would be apprecited.

Comment: without knowing what is inside the `.gitignore` and what files you want to ignore in the folders it is VERY hard to tell what is wrong

Comment: looking at the title you want it in the search result or just git, there is a setting named like `files.exclude`, search settings for `exclude`

Comment: It's a lot of file types (for example .pch) this is why I didn't specify them. I just wanted to carry the rules that would be applied if I would have opened the ParentDIr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a limitation in VS Code, which has been resolved now that [pull request #140022](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/140022) is merged. Currently you can achieve what you want by enabling the setting **Search: Use Parent Ignore Files**.

Answer (score 0):

you can and should create a global .gitignore file, like this for instance:

```
touch ~/.gitignore_global
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only that can work using "parent ignore files", it now can work *even if* you are *not* in a Git repository, using VSCode 1.80 (June 2023).

See [issue 182958](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182958): "`.gitignore` files don't take effect in Search if there is no `.git` folder".

It is completed in [PR 183368](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/183368): "Respect `gitignore` file even when not in a git repository".

You can test it today with [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)